# How to get nearest location based on user location from array of lat, long: react, leaflet

Tags: reactjs, leaflet, react-leaflet

I have a react app that shows bike stations. I want to display nearest stations on dashboard. Is there any easier way to do that with react ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can loop through all markers and look which has the shortest distance. `map.distance(USER_LATLNG, BIKE_STATION_LATLNG)`